# Sampling strategies in multi-target classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, multilabel, smote

I am dealing with multi-target binary classifications (I have two targets). I need to use a sampling strategy. I have tried imblearn.pipeline but I'm getting the same error as this time when I'm trying to resample before training.

```
for dataset in dataset_list:
        smote = SMOTE()
        X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(dataset.X_train, dataset.y_train)
        model = clone(model_class)
        model.fit(X_resampled, y_resampled)
        preds = model.predict(dataset.X_test)


Imbalanced-learn currently supports binary, multiclass, and binarized encoded multiclass targets. Multilabel and multioutput targets are not supported.
```

Any suggestions for that? I searched a lot and most articles are about multi-class and not multi-targets.

Comment: Why do you feel you have to do anything special to handle the imbalance?

Comment: @Dave cause I have a very low precision and high recall

Comment: You might be interested in the discussion and links here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any

Comment: @Hanna do you have unequal misclassification costs for your application.  As long as you have a fair amount of data, the imbalance itself is not a problem.  If low precision and high recall is unacceptable then that is an indication that the misclassification costs are unequal (false positive cost is not equal to false negative costs).  A better approach is to ignore the imbalance and work out what your misclassification costs are, and then use cost-sensitive learning.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Although you are right that this could be solved by assigning different misclassification costs, the training time is maybe also important. If one would remove samples that don't contribute much more information, that could reduce training time.

Comment: @moi that is missing the point, the problem is that class imbalance is not a good reason for up- or down- sampling the data as class imbalance is rarely inherently problematic.  If you do down-sample for computational reasons, you also need to recalibrate the output of the classifier to compensate for the training set class frequencies differing form the operational ones.  Class imbalance is **not** solved by assigning misclassification costs - the misclassification costs are part of the problem specification - a part that is all too often ignored when there is a class imbalance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in a similar case to calculate individual sample weights that balance each target:

- Given a DataFrame:

  ```py
  properties = ["a", "b"]

  N = 100
  df = pd.DataFrame(
      [[random.choice(values) for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(N)],
      columns=properties,
  )
  ```
- Calculate the frequency of each combination of target values:

  ```py
  counts = df[properties].value_counts()
  ```
- Calculate the total frequency of each target value individually, e.g. the mean:

  ```py
  for p in properties:
    counts.groupby(level=p).sum().mean()
  ```
- Apply [Iterative proportional fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting). This will calculate new counts for each combination of target values so that the desired total frequency is achieved. A few iterations should be enough.

  ```py
  new_counts = counts.copy()
  maxiter = 20
  for _ in tqdm(range(maxiter)):
      for i, p in enumerate(properties):
          factor = counts.groupby(level=p).sum().mean() / new_counts.groupby(level=p).sum()

          for v, f in factor.items():
              mask = new_counts.index.get_level_values(p) == v
              new_counts[mask] *= f
  ```
- Divide to get weights for each combination of target values:

  ```py
  weights = new_counts / counts
  ```
- Assign weight to each sample:

  ```py
  df["sample_weight"] = df.progress_apply(lambda row: weights[tuple(row[properties])], axis=1)
  ```
- Now you can randomly sample using the calculated sample weights.

Comment: Why is balancing the classes a good thing to do?  What practical applications would benefit from this (it is making assumptions about the relative costs of different misclassifications - what is the justification for doing so?)

Comment: I can not give a theoretical explanation. From my (engineering) standpoint, everything that helps to achieve a certain goal (like maximum mean precision and recall, or reducing training time) is a good thing to do.

Comment: that is precisely my point.  Why is improving maximum mean precision etc. a good thing to to?  The problem is that every time someone sees a class imbalance they are immediately advised to use resampling/re-weighting algorithms rather than consider what the correct performance criterion actually is and what is important for the particular application - hence my question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611180/sampling-strategies-in-multi-target-classification/633291?noredirect=1#comment1140548_611180

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I have read your comments here (and some others). Do you have any different advice / material to read? So far your comments under this question have not been particularly helpful to me...

Comment: In general, you don't need to do *anything* because of class imbalance, as long as your data isn't very small, it does not introduce any undue bias.  You need to consider the needs of the application, such as misclassification costs.  Unequal misclassification costs justify cost-sensitive learning or resampling or reweighting, imbalance does not.  So you need to understand the application *first*.  If the misclassification costs are unknown, you should not be using any threshold based performance metric (e.g. F1 or accuracy) as you don't have the information required to set the threshold.

Comment: I have given the advice more than once in this discussion - you need to work out what is important for your application (i.e. you need to understand the problem) in order to decide what metrics are appropriate, and then you decide what techniques you need to apply in order to optimise performance relative to those metrics.  There has been a lot of literature on cost-sensitive learning and it is covered by most good textbooks on ML and pattern recognition.

Comment: Imbalance does not mean you need to do anything.  If the misclassification costs are equal, it is quite possible for the optimal classifier to classify everything as belonging to the majority class.  In that case any re-balancing/re-weighting is making the performance of the classifier worse.